# Query to find all users between an age range from their birth_date with index

Tags: postgresql

My query is doing this:

```
where 
      ST_DWithin(
        "profile".location :: geography, ? :: geography, 
        ?
      ) 
      and EXTRACT (
        YEAR 
        FROM 
          age(profile.birth_date)
      ) BETWEEN ? :: integer 
      AND ? :: integer
```

Where I saw:

```
Never Used Indexes  public  profile profile_birth_date_idx  0   0   16 kB   56 kB
```

This makes sense because the btree index is just on `birth_date`, but it's calculating the age, so not used.

Is there a good query for birth_date => age that will take advantage of an index?

Comment: You should show us the full query, but that aside, your `WHERE` clause almost certainly can't use a B-tree index.  But, Postgres had other types of indices which might work here.

Comment: Where did you see "*Never Used Indexes*" - that's not something that Postgres normally displays

Comment: https://github.com/pgexperts/pgx_scripts/blob/master/indexes/unused_indexes.sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you disable sequential scans, it might use your index:

```
SET enable_seqscan TO off;
```

Running an `EXPLAIN` on your query after turning sequential scans off is a good way to see if the index itself is working.

I've created a similar query and indeed, it picks up the index:

```
db=# explain analyze select * from foo where date_part('year', age(birth_date)) = 5;
                                                                     QUERY PLAN
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather  (cost=1000.42..4801.93 rows=500 width=8) (actual time=23.161..24.732 rows=365 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using foo_birth_date_idx on foo  (cost=0.42..3751.93 rows=208 width=8) (actual time=19.467..19.667 rows=122 loops=3)
         Filter: (date_part('year'::text, age((CURRENT_DATE)::timestamp with time zone, birth_date)) = '5'::double precision)
         Rows Removed by Filter: 33212
         Heap Fetches: 41207
 Planning time: 0.114 ms
 Execution time: 24.798 ms
(9 rows)
```

You might want to change your query so that you're directly comparing to `birth_date` rather than a derived value of it. The following should be equivalent:

```
db=# explain analyze select * from foo where birth_date >= now() - make_interval(years := 5) and birth_date < now() - make_interval(years := 4);
                                                            QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using foo_birth_date_idx on foo  (cost=0.43..20.71 rows=364 width=8) (actual time=0.021..0.142 rows=365 loops=1)
   Index Cond: ((birth_date >= (now() - '5 years'::interval)) AND (birth_date < (now() - '4 years'::interval)))
   Heap Fetches: 365
 Planning time: 0.198 ms
 Execution time: 0.215 ms
(5 rows)
```

Even with `enable_seqscan` set to `on` (the default), it still picks up this index. Also notice how much faster it is (factor 100).

Thus, for you query, change the conditions to the following and it should pick up the index.

```
WHERE
      ST_DWithin(
        "profile".location :: geography, ? :: geography,
        ?
      )
      AND birth_date >= now() - make_interval(years := ?::integer)
      AND birth_date < now() - make_interval(years := ?::integer)
```